# For what $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ is $\{(x,y) \in A \times B \mid x^2-y^2=0\}$ a well defined bijection?

Tags: functions, multisets

For what $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ is relation $\{(x,y) \in A \times B \mid x^2-y^2=0\}$ a well defined bijection from $A$ to $B$?

This concept is pretty new for me so I'm not sure how to show this on the right way.

Comment: Well, you can take simply $A=B= \{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands $x^2 - y^2 = 0$

$x = y$ or $x = -y$

So, how do we restrict $A$ and $B$ so that only one of the above holds?

Restrict $A$ to either the positive reals or the negative reals, and $B$ to either the positive reals or the negative reals.

And then for every $x\in A$ there will be a unique $y\in B$ that satisfies the relation.  And for every $y \in B$ there is one $x\in A$

Comment: But theres an infinite number of others.  Take any set A where for any $x \ne 0 \in A; -x \not \in A$.  Let $B = \{x \in \mathbb R| x \in A or -x \in A, -x \not \in B\}$.  But $A = [0, \infty) = B$ is probably the easiest.  But, for giggles $A = \mathbb N$ and $B = \{(-1)^nn|n \in \mathbb N\}$ will also work.

Comment: as will $A - \{5, \sqrt{\frac 1 {\pi}}\}; B = \{-5, \sqrt{\frac 1{\pi}}\}$